# can I use Vuetify in nativescript-vue?

Tags: nativescript, vuetify.js, nativescript-vue

[Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/) seems to be an useful Framework. I was wondering if it's possible to use it inside our NativeScript apps with VUE.js

I have tried :

`yarn add vuetify`

```
<v-btn :href="source"
       icon
       large
       target="_blank"
       v-on="on"
      >
       <v-icon large>mdi-code-tags</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

**But Error says:**

> No known component for element v-btn.

Comment: **NativeScript !== Cordova**, so you can't. Vuetify is purely browser dependent / HTML DOM based components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NativeScript !== Cordova**, so you can't. Vuetify is purely browser dependent / HTML DOM based components.

Answer (score 2):

Though Manoj is right to point out that you can't use it like you intendet to do but you still can use a [WebView](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/web-view) in NativeScript to display your web application. Some apps in the appstores do just that - they use Nativescript for the Main-UI with device features and the webview to show the web application.